# how best to retrieve a longtext mysqli database field as json

Tags: php, jquery, json, mysqli

I'm retrieving fields from a mysqli database. One of the fields is text, and in some records, is very long with html tags in it.

I'm using php to retrieve the data and echo to jquery.

Jquery:

```
$.post("php/myfile.php", function(data){
        console.log(data);
});
```

php:

```
require_once ('constants.php'); 
$db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit;
}
$qNations = "SELECT b.Country, a.CountryCode, a.population, a.GDP, a.Income_level, b.Name, b.Age, b.Occupation, b.Origin, b.Neighborhood, b.Notes FROM countries a, people b where a.CountryID = b.CountryID order by a.Country";
$result = $db->query($qNations);
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

$db->close();
echo json_encode($data);
```

If I remove the Notes field, all is good. The json is valid. But once I put the Notes field back into the query, the returned json is not valid.

Any ideas where I should start to emend this problem please?

Comment: can you post the data of the notes column

Comment: just my guess, probably you should escape chars of your notes value?

Comment: @bondythegreat: json_encode should create the escape chars.

Comment: @Tarun: It's too long to publish here.

Comment: IMHO you can try extract 1 or 2 datas as sample at the moment, pick the data with very simple notes' value, and try other long/complicated notes.. to see if the invalid json persist or not.

Comment: Well, for some reason, the json object in FF is valid. I can't seem to get to validate when I take the json object from Chrome, tho.

Comment: Does Chrome console give you any hints as to at what _position_ it considers your JSON data to be invalid? If so, check around that position to see what characters (or maybe byte values) are there.

Comment: At this point, it seems to be pulling in OK. I don't know what went wrong before... . Thank you Tarun, bondy and CBroe for your replies!